# Can I export a table made on Tableau to Excel (Not the underlying data, but the final table)?

Tags: excel, tableau-api

The table format has to be retained.

[image]

Comment: Please see the following and reformat your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great way to generate a download that doesn't include all the other fields that are normally included with "underlying data": [The Greatest Tableau Tip EVER: Exporting CSV made simple!](http://www.vizwiz.com/2014/03/the-greatest-tableau-tip-ever-exporting.html)

Answer (score 0):

From the menu: Worksheet->Export->Crosstab to Excel

Comment: I realized what the issue was. I have been using Tableau Public which doesn't have this feature. It's available in the desktop version. Thanks though.